# ASP.Net: How to set focus on a empty field when user changes the tab

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a aspx web page taht contains 2 tabs. Each one show a different usercontrol.

The first UserControl has some fields that need to be validated (should not be empty). When the user clicks at the button "next" to go to the next tab it works fine, the field that is empty gets focused. But when the user goes manually to the next tab clicking on the tab (like we do in web browsers) and try to do something, the buttons are blocked because of the validator, but the focus doesn't go back to the previous tab.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Could you provide code or visualise this somehow? Difficult to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: The code is too long and it is portuguese =(. But basically, if you leave an empty textfield in the first tab, change to the second tab and click in SAVE, it is blocked because there is a empty field at the first tab, but I want to set focus at this empty field.

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. I'll take a look at it!

Comment: I tried Page_ClientValidate(). It blocks the other tab until I fill all the fields on the first tab. But I'm having problems with javascript, I have to click twice in a button to make it work.

Comment: If you already have code that hinders the user from saving, you should be able to just do something like this: `$('#textBoxID').focus();` in your javascript right where you do your control.

Comment: I am using the <asp:RequiredFieldValidator>. It seems to be working,  is putting the messagem in front of the empty field saying "You must fill this", and blocks all the buttons, but I still on the wrong tab, it is not sending me back to the tab that contains the empty field

Comment: It actually seems to be a bug. According to this source: http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/a-quick-fix-for-the-validator-setfocusonerror-bug <- What he did was to do it in code behind c# instead, which also is pretty simple. Just make a button click event , check if tb1 and tb2 contains what it should. If not, set focus on the textbox that failed first. Otherwise this could be done client side, using javascript. But c# is definitely easier, in my opinion.